# How to control what happens when a view's wrap_content exceeds its parent's width/height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In Android, given any `View` - I want its height/width to both be **wrap_content** - but I don't want this value to ever exceed its parent. How do I achieve this in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width/height of a View can never exceed its parent. Just use wrap_content.

Comment: I was setting a view's minimum height somewhere by accident, and not setting the view's height directly. Oops!